# ACL doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, acl

I tried to add new checkbox into `System -> Permissions -> Roles`.
I added this xml at the `adminxml.xml`, but it is doesn't work. Where is my fault ?

I want to block `Catalog -> Product/Category Filter`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <config>
        <menu>
            <catalog>
                <children>
                    <blocks translate="title" module="agentproductblocks">
                        <title>Product/Category Filtering</title>
                        <action>agentproductblocks/adminhtml_blocks</action>
                        <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                    </blocks>
                </children>
            </catalog>
        </menu>

        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <catalog>
                            <blocks translate="title" module="agentproductblocks">
                                <title>Product/Category Filtering</title>
                                <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                            </blocks>
                        </catalog>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <catalog>
            <children>
                <blocks translate="title" module="agentproductblocks">
                    <title>Product/Category Filtering</title>
                    <action>agentproductblocks/adminhtml_blocks</action>
                    <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                </blocks>
            </children>
        </catalog>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <catalog>
                        <children>
                            <blocks translate="title" module="agentproductblocks">
                                <title>Product/Category Filtering</title>
                                <sort_order>300</sort_order>
                            </blocks>
                        </children>
                    </catalog>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Comment: ty. Again u help me. U a the best